# How can I get Data Annotations from WCF Service / Stored Procedure model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, razor, data-annotations

I have a WCF Application with a mapped Entity Data Model. The Data Annotations are not working as expected.

The results with the table filled:

```
User            BirthDate               Savings
John Smith      1978-02-23 00:00:00     342
Susan Erikssen  1983-01-30 00:00:00     7323
```

This is the source code:

Calling a stored procedure to get users info:

```
public class Users : IUsers
{
    public List<sp_Get_Users> GetUsers()
    {
        var db = new DbEntities();
        return db.sp_Get_Users().ToList();
    }    
}
```

The service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUsers
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<sp_Get_Users> GetUsers();
}
```

The stored procedure model, as you can see I added some Data Annotations:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public partial class sp_Get_Users
{
    [Display(Name = "User Id")]
    public int User { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public Nullable<decimal> Savings { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var svc = new WcfSvc.UsersClient(); 
        return View(svc.GetUsers());
    }
}
```

Razor view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.WcfSvc.sp_Get_Users_Result>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Savings)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Savings)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```